# how to use PyV8 and httplib to interpret javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I would like to write my own web test engine that will request (get/post) my wsgi application and i would like my client to interpret the return page that contains some javascript code.

Basically it is how to use a PyV8 to make a headless browser.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really want to do this project yourself, have you considered using [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) ([home page](http://www.phantomjs.org/))? It's a headless WebKit with support for scripting in Javascript, and has both C++ and [Python](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs) implementations (though the Python version seems slightly less well-supported than the C++ version, and there was some chatter on the mailing list about discontinuing Python development).

Comment: Thanks, just discovered it yesterday, it is my new favorite thing of all time :).

Comment: Yes, it sure beats `curl` :-). Usually I use something like Nokogiri to do these sorts of things, but PhantomJS is very nice.

Comment: PhantomJS sounds very interesting. But I am still interestng how to assemble together a javascript engine and dom